# How can I check if a Laravel Model relation has changed before saving?

Tags: php, laravel, model

I'm trying to detect whether a particular `HasOne()` relation has changed on one of my models before saving. I tried to hook into a model observer and use the `getDirty()` method, but this seems to only return standard model attributes, not relations:

```
// Observers
public static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    Mission::updating(function($mission) use ($missionMailQueuer) {
        $attrs = $mission->getDirty();
    });
}
```

Is there any way to detect a relationship change too?